# Receiving an Unknown iOS Notification -- Audio Only

Tags: ios, notifications

I occasionally receive an iOS notification (an Apple push notification) that has sound only and no text.  Because it has no text, it does not appear in the notification center and I therefore cannot determine what app is causing this.  Kind of annoying.

Is there anyway to identify which app is sending an audio-only notification?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can, you just have to do some digging around to find the particular one that is causing the noise. If you go into your Settings application on your iDevice, and go into the `Notifications Options Tab` and look for apps that have the sounds attribute available.  As seen the in the screen shot below highlighted in red.

[image]

Selecting that one will take you further into the customizations and see if the app is sending other notifications, as shown below, this one does sound and badge and can be seen in the lock screen.  Toggling those on and off will help you find the culprit.

[image]

You will be looking for an App that is only making noise, look for one that says noise only and everything else is turned off, that one will most likely be the problem.  You can then turn on other notifications so that it will be more helpful. If you find more than one app that is noise only, enable more notification types to help you narrow down which one it is. Once you find it, you can disable it or change the setting any which way you want.

I hope that this answer helps you narrow down the noisy notifier.

Comment: Some good thoughts, but I don't have an app that has sound notifications on only.  Having coded push notifications myself, I know that an app can send a notification with a blank text field -- so I suspect that is what is happening.

Comment: There isn't a way to see that particular option unfortunately. You could try turning on more notifications for Apps that you think are the culprit.  Do you remember when you started getting them and which Apps you installed then? There isn't any Apple iOS solution besides tinkering with settings until you figure out which one it is. Maybe turing on Badges if they are an option will allow you to see which ones are lighting up. Turn on badges for every app you think is the culprit and compare those apps when ever you get that wordless notification.

Comment: Yeah.  I wish no-text notifications would still appear somehow in the notification center.

Comment: Well, as you know, when programming most things with blanks or nils, you tend to ignore them or have exceptions for them since they would be confusing behavior. People who got blank notifications would think that there is something wrong with their Device or something. I hope that I was at least able to help you out though.

Comment: IMO no-text notifications should not be allowed. This is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

[How to find the source of a sound on an iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54119/how-to-find-the-source-of-a-sound-on-an-iphone) suggests it may be GMail.  One of the answers offers a way to trace it to a specific app.